# How do I fix "System requires update" when trying to run a Car App Library app on the Android Automotive OS emulator?

Tags: android, android-automotive

I've followed the steps in https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/automotive-os to add support for Android Automotive OS, but when I try to run the app or open it for the launcher, I get the following screen:

[image: "System requires update" screen]

How do I fix this and get my app running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the "Check for updates" button will take you to the Google Play Store page for the [Google Automotive App Host](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.automotive.templates.host), which is the Car App Library host application on Android Automotive OS vehicles. You can also open the same page by running `adb shell am start https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.automotive.templates.host`.

You'll need to be logged into a Google account on the emulator in order for this page to load and for you to be able to download and install the updates to the app. After updating the host, you should be able to run your app as expected.